# powerbuilder importfile() exception handling

Tags: powerbuilder

I am doing a dw_1.ImportFile() and getting the standard Datawindow errors:
1.  "Item '???' does not pass the validation test."
2.  "Item validation error on IMPORT.  Continue IMPORT?"

Is there a way to use a Try..Catch block to handle the exception(s) without displaying the ugly messageboxes?

I've already tried the standard Catch statements

```
CATCH (PBXRuntimeError re)
CATCH (DWRuntimeError dwre)
CATCH (throwable ObjError)
CATCH (RuntimeError re)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like importfile throws an exception you can catch. It does however raise an itemerror event. You may be able to suppress the messagebox by returning a 1. The default returns 0.

hth,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Validation errors do not throw exceptions because this is a normal event that a datawindow can handle via the itemerror event. You can code this to suppress the Validation message.

Answer (score 0):

If you import to a DataStore first, you won't get message dialogs; you'll just get a failure return code. Then, if successful, you can do something like a RowsCopy() to get the data into the DataWindow.

Good luck,

Terry